# AES encryption in JS, decrypt in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, encryption

When my form gets submitted, it will first make a request to this controller action to get the server's public key:

```
public function preprocessPayment(Request $request) {
    // Get public key
    $publicKey = $this->EncryptionService->getPublicKey();

    // Generate iv
    $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true, 
        'data' => [
            'public_key' => $publicKey,
            'iv' => $iv
        ]
    ]);
}
```

After that, in my client, I'm going to generate a secret key using AES via CryptoJS, that will later be encrypted with the `public_key`.

Then, the form data will be encrypted in AES using the AES secret key, and then the following payload will be submitted to the server:

```
{
    secret_key: xxx,
    iv: xxx,
    form_data: {...}
}
```

The AES encrypted data will be processed here:

```
public function storePayment(Request $request) {
    // Decrypt AES secret key (that was encrypted with the RSA public key),
        // using RSA private key
    // Decrypt AES client data with secret key
    // Store data in database
}
```

My question is, how will I do the AES secret key generation and encryption on the client side using CryptoJS? Could not seem to find any good documentation about it. How should I format the data so it will be accepted by the server for decryption?

And I'm stuck with decrypting AES in PHP, because it requires a `$tag` and I don't know where to get that when everything is coming from the client.

```
$originalData = openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-128-gcm', $secretKey, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
```

I found this link: http://cryptojs.altervista.org/js-php/, but I'm not sure how to make it work because I'm not sure where to locate the needed scripts.

**Edit:**

I made a mistake, for decrypting on the server, I was using `aes-128-gcm` instead of `aes-256-cbc`. When I corrected it, I was able to decrypt without the `$tag`.

Comment: `CryptoJS` is described e.g. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/). An example of key generation can be found [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#pbkdf2). [Here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input) and [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output) the parameters for encryption/decryption are described in more detail. Note that the key must be passed as `WordArray`. Otherwise it is interpreted as a passphrase.

Comment: GCM is preferable over CBC because it also authenticates the ciphertext (i.e. the ciphertext cannot be modified unnoticed). The tag is optional either way. That being said, what you're doing here doesn't seem to offer any additional security over simply using TLS (which you need necessarily, since you trust the JavaScript to generate a good key).

Comment: GCM is kind of useless if the encrypted AES key can be replaced by the attacker. You need to sign the message or ciphertext.

Comment: No, you encrypt the shared secret with the public key of the server, the server authenticates by showing that it is able to decrypt the shared secret by validating that the derived session keys are identical. And yes, the shared secret can be directly used as a key in this case. There is a lot wrong, but this is not one of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AES-256 key is nothing more than 32 random bytes. So you create the key by using a cryptographically secure random number generator.

However, both RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 and AES-CBC are vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. So not only can an adversary change the message, the message is also not kept confidential. In other words, you can use 256 bit keys as much as you want, but you should not create your own transport protocol, because the *perceived* security just isn't there.

You could sign the ciphertext, but that has problems as well - generally we sign then encrypt.

Use TLS.

Comment: Hello, yes, thank you so much for your input. We already are using TLS. I myself was confused why I was being asked to do this because I thought using TLS would suffice. Apparently they just wanted to add this additional layer so the data is not easily readable (to the server as well???) if it somehow ends up somewhere else, like in another server (but TLS should already cover this???) before getting to its original destination.

Comment: I hope you mean "intended" destination, there is no such thing as original destination, after all, unless the destination has changed :) It is possible to use PKCS#1 and CBC for data *at rest* and no, TLS traffic will be unencrypted after it has come out of the "tunnel" (the receiving socket). You'd still need to worry about padding  and other plaintext oracle attacks though, because automated decryption may still present a possible attacker with an attack surface.

Comment: I see, I'm new to this so I'm still trying to completely wrap my head about what you said, but it's very helpful. But based on what I know so far, TLS should suffice. I've tried looking around for the advantages of having client-side encryption (at least when done the way I'm trying to), and the common comment that I see is that TLS will suffice. `"TLS traffic will be unencrypted after it has come out of the "tunnel" (the receiving socket)...."` Does that mean client-side encryption still has valuable advantages?

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep the data secure so that it cannot be read by admins or hackers that access the server and e.g. only process it by the client or by the back office. Then it can be an additional layer, but only if applied properly. And as a hacker with full access could also alter the JS encryption the amount of protection it offers is rather limited. For that reason I'd only recommend it if there are very specific requirements to apply it.